Ошибка при попытке отправить фотографию Aiogram Telegram
Я не могу понять, каким образом отправить фото, которое отправил пользователь. Легче самому посмотреть на код:
async def set_picture(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
   await bot.delete_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id)
   bot_message = await call.message.answer("Отправьте обложку книги:")
   await state.update_data(bot_message_id=bot_message.message_id)
   await state.set_state(ReadingStates.set_picture)

@dp.message(ReadingStates.set_picture)
async def set_picture(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
  photo_file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
  file = await bot.get_file(photo_file_id)
  file_path = file.file_path
  print(file_path)
  await state.update_data(picture=file_path)
  data = await state.get_data()
  bot_message_id = data.get("bot_message_id")
  await bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=bot_message_id)
  await message.answer(f"✅Обложка установлена!")
  await state.set_state(ReadingStates.starting)
  message_text, builder, is_picture = await get_menu(state)
  if is_picture:
    picture = data.get("picture")
    await bot.send_photo(photo=picture, caption=message_text, chat_id=message.chat.id, reply_markup=builder.as_markup())
  elif is_picture == False:
    await message.reply(message_text, reply_markup=builder.as_markup(), parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)

Я уже пробовал и через types.InputFile(), и через open(). Вот похожая статья, однако при попытке использовать open() я получал ошибку:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'photos/file_0.jpg'

А почему по file_id не отправить? Для чего грузить изображение туда-сюда?

Я без понятия как, поэтому и тут.

В смысле как? Вот же, ты его получил: photo_file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id. Далее подставляй его сюда: await bot.send_photo(photo=photo_file_id, caption=message_text, chat_id=message.chat.id, reply_markup=builder.as_markup()). Можно даже без промежуточной переменной. Кроме того, отправка медиа по file_id - это рекомендованный способ передачи
